# Change icon by selecting icon from list

Tags: javascript, angular, ionic-framework, ionic2, ionic3

**Brief Explanation:**

I have placed 1 icon on `home.html` and I have some a list of icons as well. I just want to replace the icon with the icon I choose from the list. Below is  my **home.html** code

```
<ion-item>
<!--Replace below icon by selecting icon from below ion-list -->
        <i class="fa fa-battery-empty" style="color: red;"></i> Battery Level Empty
      </ion-item>

  <ion-list>
    <ion-item>
      <i class="fa fa-battery-empty" style="color: red;"></i> Battery Level Empty
    </ion-item>
    <ion-item>
      <i class="fa fa-battery-1"></i> Battery Level 1
    </ion-item>
    <ion-item>
      <i class="fa fa-battery-2"></i> Battery Level 2
    </ion-item>
    <ion-item>
      <i class="fa fa-battery-3"></i> Battery Level 3
    </ion-item>
    <ion-item>
      <i class="fa fa-battery-4" style="color: green;"></i> Battery Level 4
    </ion-item>
  </ion-list>
```

I have to use DOM sanitizer for some HTML dynamic operations, it will be ok if this needs JS/jQuery way on `home.ts` side.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

**Component Side :**

```
battery_level = 'empty'
```

**Template Side :**

```
<ion-item>
    <i class="fa fa-battery-{{battery_level}}" 
    [ngStyle]="{'color': battery_level=='empty' ? 'red' : battery_level=='4' ? 'green' : 'black' }"
    ></i> Battery Level {{battery_level}}
</ion-item>

<ion-list>
    <ion-item (click)='battery_level = "empty"'>
        <i class="fa fa-battery-empty" style="color: red;"></i> Battery Level Empty
    </ion-item>
    <ion-item (click)='battery_level = "1"'>
        <i class="fa fa-battery-1"></i> Battery Level 1
    </ion-item>
    <ion-item (click)='battery_level = "2"'>
        <i class="fa fa-battery-2"></i> Battery Level 2
    </ion-item>
    <ion-item (click)='battery_level = "3"'>
        <i class="fa fa-battery-3"></i> Battery Level 3
    </ion-item>
    <ion-item (click)='battery_level = "4"'>
        <i class="fa fa-battery-4" style="color: green;"></i> Battery Level 4
    </ion-item>
</ion-list>
```

**[WORKING DEMO](https://stackblitz.com/edit/ionic-battery-level)**

Comment: by default it is not showing any icon, but when we click it shows the clicked icon, what to do  ?

Comment: @user2828442 , `battery_level = 'empty'` put this in component

Comment: i did, it was not doing, i closed visual studio, reopened, ionic serve and it showed...what editor are you using to code ?

Comment: @user2828442, same visual studio code , please check updated answer for color changes also